# Automatically creating buttons and making them into an accordion

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function that creates buttons deepending on what month it is. If it is February, then 28 buttons, March, then 31 buttons and so on. Then I have this function that creates an accordion. But, my problem is that I cannot connect both of them. I want the buttons that is created by the javascript to work as an accordion. Not quite sure on how to do that. So my question is how can I use my function for the accordion to the buttons that are created according to the month?
Code snippet below and jsfiddle for the buttons: https://jsfiddle.net/20psfauc/6/

function and html for the buttons:

```
var showDate = new Date();
var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June",
              "July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var weeks = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuseday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];



function drawTable(forDate) {
    var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
    var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
    var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        table.appendChild(newRow);
        for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
            var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);
            var textarea = document.createElement('button')
            textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
            textarea.setAttribute("class", "row");
            //textarea.setAttribute("id", some_value);
            newRow.appendChild(textarea);
            textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");
            textarea.setAttribute("day",  newdate + "-" + day1 );
            textarea.innerHTML = newdate + "-" + day1;
            cellsToDraw--;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
    drawTable(showDate );
};

function next() {
    if (showDate.getMonth() == 11) {
        showDate.setMonth( 0 );
        showDate.setFullYear( showDate.getFullYear()+1 );
    } else {
        showDate.setMonth( showDate.getMonth()+1 );
    }
    document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
    drawTable( showDate );
}
  function daysInMonth(month, year) {
         var days;
         switch (month) {
           case 1: // Feb, our problem child
           var leapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
           days = leapYear ? 29 : 28;
           break;
           case 3:
           case 5:
           case 8:
           case 10:
           days = 30;
           break;
           default:
           days = 31;
          }
          return days;
        }

      <h1 id="displayingMonth"></h1>
  <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse";>
```

function for the accordion

```js
  

 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

    var active = checkIfAnyVisible();
    if (active) {
      active.className = 'panel';
      active.style.maxHeight = null;
    }

    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      panel.className = 'panel';
    } else if (!checkIfAnyVisible()) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      panel.className = 'panel active';
    }
  });
}

function checkIfAnyVisible() {
  for (var i=0; i<acc.length; i++) {
    if (acc[i].nextElementSibling.className.includes('active')) {
      return acc[i].nextElementSibling;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.row {
  color: grey;
  width: 13%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.panel {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button class="row"> 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>1 content</p>
</div>

<button class="row"> 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>2 content </p>

</div>

<button class="row"> 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>3</p>
```

All help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined the function and made some minor adjustments. is that what you meant?

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        .row { color: grey;  width: 13%;  transition: 0.4s;  margin: 0 auto;}
        .panel { max-height: 0; transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; overflow: hidden;  width: 100px;  float: left;  background-color: yellow; display: inherit;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1 id="displayingMonth"></h1>
      <button id="btn" type="button" name="btnPrev" onclick="prev();">&lt; Prev</button>
      <button id="btn" type="button" name="btnNext" onclick="javascript:next();"> Next &gt;</button>
      <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse"></table>
      <script>
        var showDate = new Date();
        var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var weeks = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuseday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
        var theForm =
  '<form><fieldset><legend>Note For today</legend><input type="text" placeholder="enter something"/></fieldset><input type="submit" value="submit"/></form>'
        function drawTable(forDate) {
          var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
          var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
          var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
          var table = document.getElementById("table");
          table.innerHTML = "";
          for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
            var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
            table.appendChild(newRow);
            for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
              var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);
              var textarea = document.createElement("button");
              textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
              textarea.setAttribute("class", "row");
              newRow.appendChild(textarea);
              textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");
              textarea.setAttribute("day",  newdate + "-" + day1 );
              textarea.innerHTML = newdate + "-" + day1;
              var textarea1 = document.createElement("div");
              textarea1.setAttribute("class", "panel");
              newRow.appendChild(textarea1);
              textarea1.innerHTML = theForm;
              cellsToDraw--;
            }
          }
          var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            var active = checkIfAnyVisible();
            if (active) {
              active.className = 'panel';
              active.style.maxHeight = null;
            }
            if (panel.style.maxHeight){
              panel.style.maxHeight = null;
              panel.className = 'panel';
            } else if (!checkIfAnyVisible()) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            panel.style.width = "100%";
            panel.className = 'panel active';
            }
          });
        }
        function checkIfAnyVisible() {
          for (var i=0; i<acc.length; i++) {
            if (acc[i].nextElementSibling.className.includes('active')) {
              return acc[i].nextElementSibling;
            } else {
              continue;
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      }
      window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
        drawTable(showDate);
      };
      function next() {
        if (showDate.getMonth() == 11) {
          showDate.setMonth( 0 );
          showDate.setFullYear( showDate.getFullYear()+1 );
        } else { showDate.setMonth( showDate.getMonth()+1 ); }
          document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
          drawTable( showDate );
        }
        function prev() {
          if (showDate.getMonth() === 0) {
            showDate.setMonth( 11 );
            showDate.setFullYear( showDate.getFullYear()-1 );
          } else { showDate.setMonth( showDate.getMonth()-1 );}
          document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
          drawTable( showDate );
        }
        function daysInMonth(month, year) {
          var days;
          switch (month) {
            case 1: // Feb, our problem child
            var leapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
            days = leapYear ? 29 : 28;
            break;
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            days = 30;
            break;
            default:
            days = 31;
          }
          return days;
        }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

EDIT: Added a basic form when user click a button - as you request on comment.

EDIT2: toggle when clicking another button.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what you did? How did you combine them?

Comment: sure, as js225 say, you should create .panel after your create button. the reason is that your accordion function control "this.nextElementSibling". I added the width: 100% when the panel is shown. As i say - "minor adjustments" (:

Comment: Alright, well I want the content (where you wrote bla bla) to be a form. So I created a form in the html, gave it the ID form, and then changed it to this:  textarea1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('form'); BUT I now get this "[object HTMLFormElement]" How can I change this so I can get a form?

Comment: Well, is there a way of only showing one tab at a time? So there is only one accordion tab that is showing, I changed my code above, please see my code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you want to happen visually on the page - I tried putting your code in a jsfiddle and I didn't see any buttons created according to the month, it seems to be missing some code.

But - If you wanted your accordion function to be useful as is for the buttons created for each day of the month, they'd need to have the same structure as the other buttons you currently use the accordion function as. They would need the classname "row", since that's how the event listener that does the accordion work gets attached. They'd also need a sibling element per button since your function calls `this.nextElementSibling`.

Update:

Thanks for the fiddle!

So in your code where you're creating buttons and setting attributes on them, don't you also want to create the "panel" element that will accordion up or down when you click the date button? I think it would make more sense to rename "textarea" to "button" and create a separate textarea element:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
var textarea = document.createElement("div");
textarea.setAttribute("class", "panel");
newRow.appendChild(textarea);
```

Then you could add an event listener to your button that modified the "panel". This isn't working 100% for me, but play around with it:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = "50px";
    }
});
```

And in the css, I added `height: 100px;` to the `.panel {}` block.
You'll still need to figure out how to get the yellow block UNDER the date, though. I hope this helps!

Another update:
If you put the button and the textarea into a parent div, they line up one under the other, although this does mean EVERY button lines up one under the other:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
var textarea = document.createElement("div");
var container = document.createElement("div");
button.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
button.setAttribute("class", "row");
textarea.setAttribute("class", "panel");
container.setAttribute("class", "container");

newRow.appendChild(container);
container.appendChild(button);
container.appendChild(textarea);
```

As a side note, I think from looking at your code you're trying to create a table where each row in the table represents a week. Right now, all of your buttons are ending up in the first row. You can see this if you inspect the table. To fix it, you'll want to change your counter here to be less than 7 instead of 31: `for (var c = 0; c < 7 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {`

When you have it working, you might want to consider switching away from table and recreating this in divs. Normally if we're using a table, we're also using `<td>`s, but I'm not sure that would work here since you want to put text below each `td`. It feels a little off to have a table with buttons and divs inside it.

Comment: Hi, all of the code is there, everything works when I try it. So I want the buttons that are created, to work as an accordion. So when you click on the buttons, content shows up, as in the code snippet.

Comment: Can you put it in jsfiddle and update your post with a link?

Comment: Jsfiddle added! So I want all of the button in the jsfiddle to work as an accordion

Comment: Updated my response - I think you want to be adding an event listener to your buttons that contains the accordion code.

Comment: Thanks! But nothing realy happens when I press any of the buttons.

Comment: I added these two lines to the function where I create the buttons: var panel = document.createElement("div");
            panel.setAttribute("class", "panel");

Comment: Did you append it to the row?
`newRow.appendChild(panel);`

Comment: Just added it! Still nothing though

Comment: I updated my post with everything I did to get it working to the point that a yellow box appears on the screen when you click and disappears when you click again.

Comment: Im not able to see anything now. Please look at the jsfiddle, I added my script there again. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't see the lines `var panel = document.createElement("div"); ` or `panel.setAttribute("class", "panel");` in your jsfiddle, did you remove that?